# JsTree design is not proper display

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Run time, I try to add child under parent node. When I click on tree branch. I call ajax file which has return list structure of child and I set under parent node but designing is not proper. find my tree structure image below

```
$(document).on('click', '.jstree-ocl', function() {
var ContactId = $(this).closest('.clsTwoLevel').attr('id');
var GroupId = $('#cboGroupName').val();
if (ContactId != undefined) {
$.ajax({
  url: 'contact-group-treeview.php',
  data: 'ContactId=' + ContactId + '&GroupId=' + GroupId,
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(response) {                        
      $("#MoreThanTwoLevel_"+ContactId).html(response);
  }
});
}
});
<div id="jstree">
  <?php
     while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($GetLevelOneTwo,    SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        ?>
   <ul>
     <li>
        <?php echo $row['Name'] . ' (' . $row['TotalCount'] . ')'; ?>
        <?php
            if ($row['TotalCount'] != 0) {
                $GetLevelTewoName = get_level_tewo_name($conn, $GroupId, $row['ContactId']);
                while ($row_level_two = sqlsrv_fetch_array($GetLevelTewoName, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    ?>
        <ul>
            <li class="clsTwoLevel" id="<?php echo $row_level_two['ContactId']; ?>">
                <?php echo $row_level_two['Name'] . ' (' . $row_level_two['TotalCount'] . ')' ?>
                <?php if ($row_level_two['TotalCount'] != 0) { ?>
                <ul>
                    <!--<div class="MoreThanTwoLevel"></div>-->
                    <li class="MoreThanTwoLevel"></li>
                </ul>
                <?php } ?>   
            </li>
        </ul>
        <?php } ?>            
        <?php } ?>
    </li>
</ul>
<?php } ?>
```

**ajax result**

```
 <ul>
   <li class="clsTwoLevel jstree-open" id="4710">Kalpnaben Jitendrabhai   Soni     (1)    
   </li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li class="clsTwoLevel jstree-open" id="19">
  Ghanshyambhai Kalubhai Patel (3)                            
      <ul>
         <li class="MoreThanTwoLevel" id="MoreThanTwoLevel_19"></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li class="clsTwoLevel jstree-open" id="4711">Mitaben Ghanshyambhai      Patel (1)               
   </li>
</ul>
```

[image]